# User Permission Issues Within Domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain, user-accounts, user-permissions

I have user that is in Domain Admins group. I am trying to access folder that has full permissions for Domain Admins group but for some reason I get "You don't currently have permission to access this folder" error, I can Continue but when I do that the user is added to permissions. I don't want single users to be added to folders permissions. The folder is on my DC and I'm trying to access it when RDP-d to DC. When i access it from my local computer \DC_NAME\c$\folder it works. What is wrong with my domain?

Comment: Mfinni is correct, but I would also like to add reference to this great Microsoft KB, last updated just a few days ago by the famed Aaron Margosis: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950934

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, this is the way permissions with UAC work.

Try the search function next time :-)

[User in domain admin group cannot access directory the group has permission to access](https://serverfault.com/questions/385879/user-in-domain-admin-group-cannot-access-directory-the-group-has-permission-to-a)

Comment: I upvoted you...even though that probably means this answer will actually be accepted and the other one you linked to will end up getting closed as a dupe with my "answer" on it. :)  (I'm always surprised to see an answer of mine when I click on a question link)